# jQuery Ajax request to MVC Controller takes to long to hit the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript method that sends an object back to my MVC controller. Pretty standard, nothing special. For whatever reason, the time it takes for the request from the ajax request to hit the MVC controller takes a whopping 1 minute and 9 seconds. I've placed timmers on all items in javascript that are being hit before the ajax request is hit and it takes less than 3ms to complete them all.

I am very unsure as to why it would take a solid minute for the ajax request to hit the MVC controller. Can anyone provide some ideas on where I should look to fix this issue? Also note, that I have other ajax requests going to other MVC actions and they do not take this long.

Comment: Looks like an issue with our system. Can you share how much RAM you have available when you run the project. Also did you try disabling Firewall and Antivirus software? Different browser same issue?

Comment: It isn't an issue with the system. Can run other jquery ajax request calls on the same page without the problem. It is only this one call for some reason. Happens on all browsers. No firewalls or antivirus.

Comment: @Xerc, were you able to figure out this issue? I am having the exact lagging problem as you described. What was the fix? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Turned out that the model that was being used for the view was a very extensive model. I was able to get around the long time by setting the controller method to take a string. In the jquery ajax request, I am sending the model data as a string. Back in the controller, I am converting the string to the model. No data loss and almost instant.